# How to exclude file to push?

Tags: git

I have repository with one file with the local settings. I have added it to .gitignore and to .git/info/exclude but it was previously pushed to server and git wants to track them.

How to exclude this file?

Comment: Did you just want to remove the file so that it's no longer tracked in future commits, or did you want to remove the file from your repo's history entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can delete that file from git's index by using `git rm <filename> --cached`

Comment: Another option, if you want to keep the old version of the file on your repository without removing it, is `git update-index --assume-unchanged file.txt`. This is nifty if you want to leave a boilerplate file on the repository without having your real data there. For example, API keys, passphrases, usernames, etc.